# Windows service keeps on failing

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a windows service which is designed to continuously retrieve messages from Azure service bus queue and pass it to other queues.I have deployed this service to one of the server computer but unfortunately the service keeps failing at a random time interval.

My application handles the exceptions and writes them to a file.The main purpose of this application is to hook up to the queue and listen all the messages continuously and never move to the Application stop stage.I'm using a timer in this application and I don't think that is causing any problem.I'd like to know what would be the best approach to handle errors and make my application stable, below is the code. Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Scheduler : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer Scheduletimer = null;

    private string servicenamespace;
    private string issuesecretkey;
    private string sourcequeue;
    private string destinationqueue;

    public Scheduler()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Scheduletimer = new Timer();
        this.Scheduletimer.Interval = 1000;//1 sec
        this.Scheduletimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        Scheduletimer.Enabled = true;
        WriteToFile("Application started : "+DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    protected void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Scheduletimer.Enabled = false;
        WriteToFile("Business logic started : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        //Business Logic code goes here
    }


    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        Scheduletimer.Enabled = false;
        WriteToFile("Application stoped : "+DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public void WriteToFile(string text)
    {
        string directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string logfilepath = directory + "LogFile.txt";


        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logfilepath, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(text);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    public void WriteErrorsToFile(Exception ex)
    {
        string directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string Errorlogfilepath = directory + "ErrorLogFile.txt";

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Errorlogfilepath, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Time Occured: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            writer.WriteLine(ex.Message +" "+ DateTime.Now.ToString());
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: First: Which timer class are you using? I tend to use `System.Timers.Timer` for services. Also: Are you ever restarting your timer in the timer event handler? And most important: **What's the error?** I don't see any exception handling here, so there must be something in the event log. Otherwise: Handle exceptions and perform logging.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I'm using the System.Timers.Timer for services, I'm not restarting my timer as you can see Scheduletimer.Enabled = false; where i want my application to run and continuously run the business logic.My business logic handles the exceptions so there's no problem with it. The error which i receive in the event viewer is "The 'Name of my service' service entered the running state." I'd like to know what this mean

Comment: So, what error are you receiving?